# How to retrieve object properties from a object parameter in a factory object?

Tags: javascript, object, hash, arguments, factory

I have this factory:

```
const task = (args) => {
    const title = args.title
    const completed = () => {
        return args.hasOwnProperty(completed) ? args.completed : false //assign default parameter of false to completed
    }

    return {
        title,
        completed
    }
}
```

and made this object:

```
const cleanRoom = task({
    title: 'Test',
    completed: true
})
```

When i try to access:

```
cleanRoom.completed()
```

I'm always getting false, even when i assigned the args object a completed property of true.

I also tried making this:

```
console.log(title in cleanRoom)
```

and it returns that title is undefined, which makes me wonder that the problem in the completed function is the return value of the args.hasOwnProperty piece.
I've spending some hours trying to solve it but haven't been able to.

Also, the point of this task is explicitly to pass an object as an argument to a factory (Avoid fixed-order arguments)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `string` as a property key:

```js
const task = (args) => {
  const title = args.title
  const completed = () => {
    return args.hasOwnProperty("completed") ? args.completed : false //assign default parameter of false to completed
  }

  return {
    title,
    completed
  }
}

const cleanRoom = task({
  title: 'Test',
  completed: true
})

console.log(cleanRoom.completed());
```